# How to Print Large Format PDF's from Chrome/Edge

Tags: printing

About a week ago, I decided to by a large format wall planner to help organize my weeks. Being the cheapskate that I am, and having a membership at the local makerspace, I decided to order a downloadable large format PDF to print myself rather than opt for the more expensive shippable version.

Naturally things aren't turning out as simply as one would hope. I cannot connect by laptop directly to the printer and have been having issues with the shared computers.

Specifically, most of the programs installed on the shared computers (chrome, Edge, gimp), have print dialogs do not have A0, A1, A2 as printable paper sizes - This means that when I send the document to the printer, it is cut into various US Letter size chunks and printed on individual pages rather than as a single document.

I'm new to big print jobs, is there a standard way/program/process that I can use here or do I need specific software, or am I simply missing a setting that I need to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the apps you mentioned don't have A0, A1 or A2 paper sizes, you can try to enter the size yourself. When you want to print in either of these apps:

- Select <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>  to open the Print (Print as system dialog) option (this option works for Chrome and Edge, not sure about Gimp).
- Click on Preferences, then select Custom Size among the Paper Size options.
- Set the width and height of the paper. Click OK, then OK. Finally click Print.

Make sure that you inserted the correct paper in the printer tray, and set/selected the correct tray before printing (in case the printer has multiple trays).

Comment: Thanks, this worked like a charm